# WPF - Deselect DataGrid items

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have the following window:

[image: Window]

When I click outside the data grid, there is still something selected, it just grays out when I change tabs and come back:

[image: Grayed out]

I wanted to deselect the items when clicked outside the datagrid, but this gives me a problem, since  the `Change` button is outside, it deselects everything and there is nothing more to change and my `Command` changes the button state do disabled:

[image: deselected]

I did this with a simple `TargetedTriggerAction`, but I can't make it work in such a way that it only fires when clicked outside the datagrid AND outside the Button. I tried to make a `GotFocus` on the grid inside the tab, but it doesn't fires, it only fires in the tab item or the tab control and basically fires everywhere when tied to it.

My structure is: Window -> DockPanel -> TabControl -> TabItem -> Grid (Stack panel for the buttons) (Datagrid)

My `TargetedTriggerAction`:

```
public class TargetedTriggerActionDataGridUnselect : TargetedTriggerAction<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        this.Target.UnselectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don´t get it. You want to deselect the item but remain the change button to be active? Or do you just want the grey background to go away (just the visual effect)?

Comment: I want to give the user the hability do deselect something, I can't see how, once I select something, it remais selected until I close the program...I don't want to make a button to deselect, I feel it's natural to click outside a datagrid and it will deselect whats inside

Comment: You can deselect a row by CTRL + Mouse click on the Datagrid row.

Comment: You are trying to achieve a conflicting functionality. If you try to deselect after clicking outside the grid, then there no way to enable the Change button since no record is selected.

Comment: Yes I know, I wanted it to deselct only when I click outside but not when I click on the button, that is, when I click in the grey area

Comment: That's the expected behavior.  I'd suggest you leave it be.  I suggest this because I played the same tune long ago.  The actual solution was to change the template.  It was a huge PITA, and when it was done, the result was so damned trivial it made me cry.  Don't cry.  Just move on.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am thinking about, I will just leave it...